# UiNavigation error when presenting a page

Tags: ios, swift, uinavigationcontroller

i'm coding Swift
In this part of my code , it supposed to open a viewcontroller when a cell in table is selected.

```
override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {


    let next = self.storyboard?.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "SVC")
    self.navigationController?.pushViewController(next!, animated: true)
    self.present(next!, animated: true, completion: nil)

}
```

it returns a error!!

> Terminating app due to uncaught exception
>   'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: 'Application tried to present
>   modally an active controller

and when i run it it works properly but when it open that specific viewcontroller it crash and screen freezes

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should either use this

```
self.navigationController?.pushViewController(next!, animated: true)
```

or this

```
 self.present(next!, animated: true, completion: nil)
```

**Edit:** Use this

```
override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {

    let next = self.storyboard?.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "SVC")
    self.navigationController?.pushViewController(next!, animated: true) 
}
```

Comment: the first one crashed again, and the second one works , but it doesn't show the back button which all the navigation controller represent !!

Comment: when you put the first one what the crash says

Comment: you can't use both together please attach last code you tried

Comment: override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
  
  
  let next = self.storyboard?.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "SVC")
  self.navigationController?.pushViewController(next!, animated: true)
  self.present(next!, animated: true, completion: nil)
  
 }

Comment: you should understand that both do the navigation but the first shows in the navigationController this is the only difference , so presenting it again in **self.present** line causes the crash